# Install gnome 3 with Gnome flashback

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments

I'm using gnome flashback but now, I want to use original Gnome 3 version. How can I install gnome 3 with this version so I can change from login screen as I have Gnome and Unity for instance.

Comment: Install `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` via `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop` - logout and choose Gnome as session in the login-manager while you re-login

Comment: Unable to find ubuntu-gnome-desktop package :/

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? If yes, which version are you using?

Comment: Yep, Ubuntu 15.05

Comment: I assume you are talking about 15.04 - not 15.05. Apart from that 15.04 is as far as i know not longer supported. I would most likely upgrade to 16.04 and then install gnome - but thats just what i would do. You could as well just search apt for the package name in 15.04 as follows: `apt-cache search gnome-desktop` and then install it via: `sudp apt-get install PACKAGE-NAME-OF-GNOME-IN-15.04`

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I searched for gnome-desktop and only appears `gnome-desktop3-data - Common files for GNOME desktop apps`